# Efficiently deleting similar numpy rows in l2 norm sense

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, sorting

Say I have a numpy array, *n* rows that are *k* dimensional (*n x k* matrix). For ease of understanding, *n* can be the number of observations, and *k* are the different variables.

Each column (variable) is standardized so its values are contained between 0 and 1.

I can easily find the *l2* distance between two rows (observations), and I could delete one of them by specifying a threshold number, under which the *l2* distance is too low and I deem these rows "too similar."

However, can I do this for the entire dataset faster than O(n^2)? It seems naive to me to fix one row and check the remaining *n-1*. Even if I delete while I check each row, if the number of similar rows is small, I'm still basically at O(n^2) time.

I'm imagining each row as a point in *k* dimensional space and basically putting a small ball around each and seeing which points fall in the ball around another point -- kind of like a means-clustering thing?

Comment: "efficiency" in the usual `numpy` sense means working with the whole-array, So if you can think in terms of identifying all the rows that are sufficiently different (or unique in some sense), and then aim to **keep** them, that would be more efficient than looking for something close, deleting that, and then again looking for something close.  "delete" means making a new array without some of the rows, thus shouldn't be done iteratively.

Comment: I don't know much about this subject, but I would guess that the answer is no unless `k` is (much) smaller than `n`. For few dimensions, you could look into KDTrees, and the scipy [implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html).